# Aggregating column values based on range

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate

I'm new to SQL and stackoverflow, forgive if my question is trivial. I have record of customers purchase quantities in a table, so I want a count of customers whose purchase fall in a range.

```
TABLE:
+-------------+----------------+
| customer_id | order_quantity |
+-------------+----------------+
|         123 |          10000 |
|         143 |           5000 |
|         999 |         200000 |
|         555 |          50000 |
+-------------+----------------+
```

The goal is to count how many customers buy < 5000, between 5000-50000 and 50000-100000 order quantities.

I used:

```
SELECT customer_id,
      CASE
         WHEN COUNT(order_quantity) < 5000
         ....
FROM purchases
```

Which isn't correct (don't even work).

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a meaningful description. What output do you want? Moreover, you want to "count", do you have a "count" in your SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select (case when order_quantity < 5000 then '[0-5000)'
             when order_quantity < 10000 then '[5000-10000)'
             else '10000+'
        end) as grp,
       count(*) as num_purchases,
       count(distinct customer_id) as num_customers
from t
group by grp
order by min(order_quantity);
```

If a customer makes more than one purchase in a given group, it is not clear if you want to count the number of purchases or the number of customers.  This does both.